# How to use eofill in the following case?

Tags: pstricks

```
\documentclass[12pt,pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-poly,pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
\psset{PstPicture=false,PointSymbol=none,PointName=none}
\PstHexagon[PolyName=A,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow]
\pscircle(0,0){1cm}
\foreach \m/\n in {1/2,2/3,3/4,4/5,5/6,6/1}{
\pstMiddleAB{A\n}{A\m}{I\m}
\pstArcOAB[linecolor=red,fillstyle=eofill]{I\m}{A\n}{A\m}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How to get a result as the following:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt,pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks,multido}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
\degrees[6]
\pscircle(0,0){2cm}
\pscustom[fillstyle=eofill,fillcolor=yellow,linecolor=red,linejoin=2]{%
  \multido{\rA=-1.5+2.0,\iA=0+2,\iB=-3+2,\rB=-0.5+2.0,\iC=1+2,\iD=-2+2}{3}{%
    \psarc(1.73;\rA){1}{\iA}{\iB} \psarcn(1.73;\rB){1}{\iD}{\iC}
  }}
\pspolygon[linecolor=blue](2;0)(2;1)(2;2)(2;3)(2;4)(2;5)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "1.73", Why can you choose it?

Comment: `sqrt(3)`  ... school mathematics .... :-)  `r*sqrt(3)/2`

Comment: And fillstyle=eofill is "always" used together with \pscustom ?

Comment: No, can also be used with  curves which have intersections. Without intersections it makes no difference to fillstyle solid.

Comment: So, you can see my code above. Can fillstyle=eofill work? ....

Comment: No, you need a continues curve. That's the reason why I switsch in my solution between `\psarc` and a following `\psarcn`

Comment: (Off topic). I just loaded https://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks-base and \psLineSegments was not updated in pst-news19.pdf . :-)